# laravel pagination problem - all links types are coming

Tags: laravel, pagination

```html
 {{ $articles->links()  }}
```

I'm using this code to display page numbers. But it shows us like this: [image]

All types are coming to the page. previous-next links, page number links, previous-next icons.
How to minimize this? I want just see page number links. how to do that. if you help me i will be glad.

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
paginator::useBootstrap();
```

to your AppServiceProvider boot method

Answer (score 0):

It worked like this:  `$articles->links('pagination::bootstrap-4')`